# ¿css3 tiene soporte en la mayoría de navegadores?

Tags: css, css3

soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo css, css3; pero ahora que estoy haciendo una pagina web me doy cuenta que con css es mas complicado que con css3.
¿vale la pena aprender a desarrollar una pagina con css o ya me enfoco en desarrollarlo solo con css3?
yo sé que css y css3 son casi lo mismo, aprendí la teoría de ambos; me refiero a si ya debería enfocarme en usar las nuevas herramientas de css3.
no sé desde cuando existe css3; por eso mi pregunta si ya tiene soporte en los navegadores. gracias...

Comment: Css como lenguaje de estilizado es solo uno y claro que debes aprenderlo, para un sitio web ocuparas n cantidad de propiedades de este

Comment: Lo que puedes usar para conocer el soporte de propiedades de css es caniuse.com

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, hay módulos y características de CSS3 ampliamente soportadas y algunas no totalmente soportadas. Debemos evitar preguntas tan amplias, y que fomenten el debate o la opinión personal. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En 1998 se comenzó el desarrollo de CSS3, publicándose los [primeros borradores en 1999](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS20/). A día de hoy, cualquier navegador lo soporta, pero hay algunas características que ciertos navegadores soportan y otros no. Incluso hay algunas que no son respetadas por los navegadores de la manera en que se debería.

Por tanto, sí te recomendaría que te centraras en CSS3, al menos para desarrollos nuevos, pero teniendo siempre un manual de referencia a mano que te diga qué característica de CSS3 está soportada por qué navegadores y desde qué versiones de los mismos.

Como comenta BetaM, una opción es la web [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/). Además puedes comprobar el estado de los módulos en [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Archive/CSS3), o buscar información en el [W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/).

Para cosas sencillas, vas a encontrar que todos los navegadores se comportan bastante bien, pero no te confíes, confirma siempre que la característica que vas a usar está disponible en los navegadores más importantes.

Comment: W3cschools tiene una [mala reputación](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com), históricamente hablando. Siempre hay fuentes más confiables de actores que están construyendo cosas (como Mozilla o Microsoft).

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoja_de_estilos_en_cascada#CSS3.1) se dice que los primeros borradores de CSS3.1 fueron liberados en 1999, y se cita al [W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs). Pero también te digo que no me he parado a corroborar la cita.

Comment: En el [enlace](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS20/) que has puesto se menciona que el 22 de junio de 1999 se presentan los primeros 3 borradores de CSS3. No veo la inconsistencia.

Answer (score 1):

si yo te recomiendo aprender todas las nuevas tecnologías ya que es lo que se va a utilizar en el futuro o en el día a día pero no cabe destacar que siempre es bueno tener mínimo lo fundamental osea saber el css normal ya que algunas cosas son las mismas que el nuevo pero lo bueno es que sigas aprendiendo mientras mas aprendas mejor así que a echarle ganas (:

Comment: Hay que cuidar la redacción. Los signos de puntuación existen para algo. Por otro lado tu respuesta parece más una opinión. ¿De qué forma esto responde la duda del OP? Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos

Comment: No es que sea *CSS normal*, el lenguaje es solo uno, te recomuendo busques y leas sobre [módulos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Archive/CSS3#:~:text=Formalmente%2C%20no%20existe%20un%20estandar,estandar%20CSS%20consiste%20en%20CSS2.)

Comment: el pregunto esto ¿vale la pena aprender a desarrollar una pagina con css o ya me enfoco en desarrollarlo solo con css3? yo di me opinion

Answer (score 1):

Creo que conviene mencionar los siguientes puntos:

- Como lenguaje de estilizado [CSS es solo uno](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html)
- El soporte a las *nuevas características* es gradual y dependerá de que tal rápido avance cada [especificación](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html)
- Para saber si una propiedad esta siendo amplia o vagamente soportada, entonces puedes usar [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) (*muy popular*)

Lo que percibes como *es más difícil con CSS que con CSS3*, se puede deber a que:

- Conforme los módulos van liberando *features* y están se vuelven ampliamente soportadas por los navegadores, para ti al final como desarrollador o desarrolladora te hará mas fácil el trabajo.

Respecto a tu pregunta sobre: *¿vale la pena aprender a desarrollar una pagina con css o ya me enfoco en desarrollarlo solo con css3?* debes tener siempre presente:

- A menos que una propiedad este o aparezca como *deprecated* entonces sigue siendo funcional (*nada recomendado pero por ejemplo `marquee` he visto que sigue trabajando y al día de hoy ya no debería hacer falta pero hey ahi está*)
- Invariablemente terminarás usando propiedades de CSS que formen parte de distintas especificaciones y eso dependerá de lo que te encuentres realizando
- CSS3 es parte del historial del lenguaje de fondo que es CSS

De forma muy muy resumida, CSS3 no es alterno o diferente a CSS, sino un grupo de propiedades que vienen a complementar a dicho lenguaje

**Referencias**

- [CSS3 INTRODUCCIÓN](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-roadmap-20010523/#whymods)
- [Módulos en CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Archive/CSS3#:%7E:text=Formalmente%2C%20no%20existe%20un%20estandar,estandar%20CSS%20consiste%20en%20CSS2.)

Answer (score 0):

Con todo lo nuevo que va saliendo en `css` y `html` es preferible verificar si está implementado en algunos navegadores o no.

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/) tiene los datos actuales de como funcionan algunas propiedades y si tienen bugs o no están implementadas. Esto depende más del navegador y el motor que esté usando pues en algún navegador puede funcionar perfectamente y en otro ni si quiera sea tomado en cuenta pues no esta implementado.

Por ejemplo flexbox, si revisas en [Can I Use: Flexbox](https://caniuse.com/flexbox) puedes observar que esta implementado prácticamente en todos los navegadores menos en IE(que raro :) )